# How to keep first 50 characters of a filename in prompt Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, line, prompt

I'm writing to you because I need to create a batch file that allows me to rename many files in .pdf keeping only the first 50 characters.

I've tried this:

```
for %i in (*.txt) do (set fName=%i)
ren %fName% %fName:~0,-11%.txt
```

But this removes only the last 11 characters.
I've tried to modify this code but I can in no way do what I need.

I think it's a very easy thing for someone who is a little more expert than me so I ask you if you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

I insert below the errors that come to me following the corrections:

```
C:\Users\---\Desktop\Conversione PDFA>for %fname:~0,50% in (*.pdf) do (set fname=%~ni)
graeiojpoghnpiofsdnpibnwapobnslnsdlekpfèwekrgpjbm was unexpected at this time.

C:\Users\---\Desktop\Conversione PDFA>for %fname:~0,50% in (*.pdf) do (set fname=%~ni)
graeiojpoghnpiofsdnpibnwapobnslnsdlekpfèwekrgpjbm was unexpected at this time.

C:\Users\---\Desktop\Conversione PDFA>for %fname:~0,50% in (*.pdf) do (set fname=%i)
graeiojpoghnpiofsdnpibnwapobnslnsdlekpfèwekrgpjbm was unexpected at this time.



C:\Users\---\Desktop\Conversione PDFA>ren %fName% !fname:~0,50!.pdf
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\Users\---\Desktop\Conversione PDFA>ren %fName% %!fname:~0,50!.pdf
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Comment: remove the last 11 chars is exactly, what you coded. Read the output of `set /?` to learn more about substring processing.

Comment: Hint #1: `%fname:~0,50%`.  Hint #2 `set fname=%%~ni`.  Hint #3 `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` combined with `!fname:~0,50!.txt` inside the for loop, not outside.

Comment: ...not forgetting to `endlocal` before ending the loop too! Please note that from a batch file, you'd also need to change `%i` to `%%i`, and then I'd suggest for better portability to change `!fname:~0,50!.txt` to `!fname:~0,50!%%~xi`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. I tried to make the corrections you recommended but I only get syntax errors. Most likely it is not clear to me where to make the change. Can you please support me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`for %fname:~0,50% ...`: just no.
`for %i in (*.pdf) do set fname=%i`: yes.

You want to rename several PDF's, so the `ren` command should be within the loop. That's possible but ugly and error-prone (especially when you are not (yet) firm in `cmd` syntax) in a single command line, so I wouldn't' suggest it. Your best approach is the use of a batch file. It's much more readable and maintainable.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (*.pdf) do (
  set "fname=%%~ni"
  ECHO ren "%%~fi" "!fname:~0,50!%%~xi"
)
```

See `for /?` for an explanation of the modifiers `%%~ni` etc.
See [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028) for the usage of `!fname!` instead of `%fname%`

**NOTE**: I "disarmed" the `ren` command for security reasons by just echoing it. When you have verified, it's exactly what you want, just remove the `ECHO`

Comment: Thank you very much it worked, but now I would like to cut the first part not the last, may you please tell me what to change?

Thanks

Comment: `!fname:~0,50!` means "take a substring starting at position `0` (the first character) and take `50` characters. `!fname:~50` takes the string starting at position `50` (the 51st char) until the end of the string (because the second parameter (length) is missing). To extract the last 50 chars, use `!fname:~-50!`(start at position `50` from the end; length is missing again, so until the end of the string) It's all described in `set /?` with examples.

Comment: It worked, thank you! the final code is this `@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (*.pdf) do (
  set "fname=%%~ni"
  ren "%%~fi" "!fname:~-46!%%~xi"
)`